# Python passing values from a method to another method

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, self

I have a problem that is driving me crazy.

I have 2 modules Main.py and Writeagile.py

on main.py i have a Ui_MainWindow class who holds all my userinterface.

in Ui_MainWindow i have a method "on_click_fetchUser":

```
def on_click_fetchUser(self):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    api = AgileApi()
    user_email = self.search_agile.text()

    if "@" and "." not in user_email:
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
        msg.setText("wrong Email")
        msg.exec_()
    else:
        api.fetchUser(email=user_email)
```

The `api.fetchUser(email=user_email)`goes in to Writeagile.py
and to the fetchUser Method:

```
def fetchUser(self,email):

    msg = QMessageBox()
    msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
    agile_user = self.agileCRM("contacts/search/email/{}".format(email), "GET", None, "application/json")  
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    try:
        fetch_user = json.loads(str(agile_user))
        if email in fetch_user['properties'][4]['value']:
            first = (fetch_user['properties'][0]['value'])
            last = (fetch_user['properties'][1]['value'])
            email = (fetch_user['properties'][4]['value'])

            return ui.agile_ui(first=first,last=last,email=email)

    except ValueError:
        return {msg.setText("User not found in Agile") ,  msg.exec_()}
```

This workes fine, and the Json information that i want is extracted and returned to a new method that is back in Ui_MainWindow, agile_ui:

```
def agile_ui(self,first,last,email):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    print(first,last,email)

    self.first_name.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "{}".format(first)))
    self.last_name.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "{}".format(last)))
    self.email.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "{}".format(email)))
```

So far everything workes like i want it to, and the Print gives me exactly what information i want.

BUT now my problem starts! 
When the method agile_ui() is "initiated" from writeagile.fetchUser()
The attributes, that are going to change the text for me:

```
self.first_name.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "{}".format(first)))
self.last_name.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "{}".format(last)))
self.email.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "{}".format(email)))
```

Don't do anything !! No errors or nothing!  nothing is happening.

If i remove everything that is passed from writeagile.fetchUser, 
and initiate agile_ui within Ui_MainWindow, the attributes work and the setText works.

Hope anyone could please help me. 
Best regards Fredrik

Comment: Those are not _"scripts"_ - they are _"modules"_. There is a difference. You cannot import a script. More importantly, these are not _"class methods"_ - they are just _"methods"_. The difference is even bigger here. Class methods don't have `self`. It may seem irrelevant, but you should learn how things are called if you want other people to understand what you are saying.

Comment: Don't forget to change the title

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

needed to change the return to only the value,
and then use the return value on the on_click_fetchUser method:

```
fetch_user = json.loads(str(agile_user))
if email in fetch_user['properties'][4]['value']:
    first = (fetch_user['properties'][0]['value'])
    last = (fetch_user['properties'][1]['value'])
    email = (fetch_user['properties'][4]['value'])

    return first,last,email


def on_click_fetchUser(self):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    api = AgileApi()
    user_email = self.search_agile.text()

    if "@" and "." not in user_email:
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
        msg.setText("Ugyldig Email")
        msg.exec_()
    else:
        result = (api.fetchUser(email=user_email))
        self.first_name.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "{}".format(result[0])))
        self.last_name.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "{}".format(result[1])))
        self.email.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "{}".format(result[2])))
```

Comment: It is ok to "accept" your own answer, if you find the best answer to your question yourself.  This is actually encouraged.